# Почему не работает обычный delete?

Tags: память, c++

Вот в этом [примере](http://webhamster.ru/mytetrashare/index/mtb0/11) демонстрируется, как создать массив объектов, у которых конструктор принимает параметры. Если мы, как они рекомендуют, отделяем выделение памяти от вызова конструктора, обычный способ очистки уже не сработает, приходится вызывать деструкторы в цикле. Если попытаться написать `delete [] foos`, всё зависнет.

Но почему?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы выделили память при помощи `new[]`, возвращать её нужно при помощи `delete[]`.

Если же вы выделили область памяти при помощи обыкновенного new, а потом сконструировали объекты при помощи placement new (`new( &foos[ i ] ) Foo( a, b );`), и освобождать надо так же: placement delete + delete на область памяти. Любое другое освобождение памяти есть по стандарту undefined behaviour, и имеет право вести себя как угодно.

В самом деле: если объект выделен при помощи `new`, он есть в списке heap-объектов. `delete` пытается найти вокруг объекта управляющие данные heap'а (например, длину куска памяти), и воспользоваться ими. Если там на самом деле таких данных не найдётся, произойдёт катастрофа. В вашем случае именно это и происходит, только с `delete[]`. Кроме того, `delete[]` к тому же пытается вызвать `delete` для каждого из объектов, для чего ему нужно знать их количество, сохраняемое в управляющем блоке во время `new[]`. Поскольку `new[]` не вызывался, всё на самом деле довольно кисло.

---

Кстати, код, на который вы ссылаетесь, насколько я понимаю, тоже не вполне верен: он считает, что по каждый объект уходит ровно `sizeof(Foo)` байт памяти, то есть для `count` объектов нужно `sizeof( Foo ) * count` байт памяти. Это неверно, если компилятор решит использовать выравнивание. (Например, объект нечётной длины может спровоцировать проблемы.) Вот [обсуждение по теме](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8720425/276994) на братском ресурсе.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, выравнивание повлияет на sizeof(Foo), а массив в любом слцучае содержит элементы, располагающиеся друг за другом. "Лишняя" память может потребоваться только тогда, когда мы пытаемся вызвать конструктор для всех элементов массива одним вызовом, т.к. нет гарантии, что размер блока, который мы выделили, не будет меньше того куска памяти, в котором вызываются конструкторы. А в примере,  на который я ссылаюсь, конструкторы вызываются индивидуально, и в не выделенную память мы не залезем.

Comment: Учитывая, что Вы имеете дело с C++, настоятельно рекомендую отказаться от new/delete в пользу vector и/или shared_ptr

Comment: @Modus: Хм. Вероятно, вы правы, из `sizeof` содержит padding. Тем не менее, ссылка на стандарт в обсуждении, на которое я ссылаюсь, говорит, что под массив выделяется дополнительный кусок (`y`).